# ZeroClipboard - copy text to clipboard not working

Tags: javascript, html, zeroclipboard

I want to try this [**DEMO**](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/zero-clipboard.php) to copy text to the clipboard by using ZeroClipboard.  I have one local folder with the index.html, ZeroClipboard.js and ZeroClipboard.swf int it.
but it does not work:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //set path
        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('ZeroClipboard.swf');
        //create client
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        //event
        clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
            clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
        });
        clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
            alert('copied: ' + text);
        });
        //glue it to the button
        clip.glue('copy');
    </script>

    <textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="5" cols="70">
        The David Walsh Blog is the best blog around!  MooTools FTW!
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy to Clipboard" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying on `localhost` or just opening the file with double click ? It should be on a server `localhost` in your case.

Answer (score 4):

You have to run a server. Because the link to you site must contain http or https. It's because of adobe flash's security settings

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, in copy button the iframe tag is generated.
You are missing one line after initializing the Zeroclipboard.Client().

**clip.setHandCursor( true );**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //set path
    ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('ZeroClipboard.swf');
    //create client
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
    //event

    clip.setHandCursor( true );          


    clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
    });
    clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
        alert('copied: ' + text);
    });
    //glue it to the button
    clip.glue('copy');
    </script>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both `ZeroClipboard.js` and `ZeroClipboard.swf` are available. To verify this you could open the console and look for the errors.
Also ensure that [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) is installed and enabled.

In all other cases the example should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the javascript before the element `box-content` is defined.

```
clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
   clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
});
```

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="5" cols="70">
        The David Walsh Blog is the best blog around!  MooTools FTW!
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy to Clipboard" />
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //set path
        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('ZeroClipboard.swf');
        //create client
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        //event
        clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
            clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
        });
        clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
            alert('copied: ' + text);
        });
        //glue it to the button
        clip.glue('copy');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: swf is fine loaded(right url when console logged), but nothing happens when button pressed...

Comment: I have tried several codes, both from library github page examples, your code, jsfiddle added to accepted answere here NONE of this is working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511001/how-can-i-get-a-simple-zeroclipboard-copy-to-clipboard-setup-working-within-jque