# How can I get a simple ZeroClipboard copy-to-clipboard setup working within jQuery on jsFiddle on a single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, copy-paste, zeroclipboard

I'm struggling to get ZeroClipboard working within a jQuery context.  The basic usage I'm after is clipping the text of each `div` with the class `copy` on click.

The following jsFiddle works on double click using the stable ZeroClipboard v1.3.3

http://jsfiddle.net/bEQ6R/

html:

```
<div class="copy">Click this text to copy this text</div>
<div class="copy">Or click this text to copy this text</div>
<p class="debug flash-loaded">Flash player is loaded.</p>
<p class="debug confirm-copy">Text Copied.</p>
<textarea placeholder="Use this textarea to test your clipboard"></textarea>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ZeroClipboard.config({ moviePath: 'http://zeroclipboard.org/javascripts/zc/ZeroClipboard_1.3.2.swf',debug: true });    
    var client = new ZeroClipboard($('.copy'));
    client.on('load', function(client) {
        $('.flash-loaded').fadeIn();
        client.on('complete', function(client, args) {
            client.setText($(this).text());
            // client.setText('Manually Set Text to This instead of the contents of the div');
            console.log(client);
            $('.confirm-copy').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Yes, I understand there are other similar ZeroClipboard questions here, but I have yet to see a simple jsFiddle version actually work. Existing fiddles I've come across are either deprecated or no longer functional for some other reason.

Also, ZeroClipboard's demo on their own site http://zeroclipboard.org/ for the same version appears to work just fine, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working solution. On the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEQ6R/3/) I changed `client.on('complete'...` to `client.on('mouseover'...` to initialize the ZeroClipboard flash file before the first click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ZeroClipboard.config({ moviePath: 'http://zeroclipboard.org/javascripts/zc/ZeroClipboard_1.3.2.swf',debug: true });

    var client = new ZeroClipboard($('.copy'));
    client.on('load', function(client) {
        $('.flash-loaded').text('Flash player loaded at ' + $.now()).fadeIn();
        client.on('mouseover', function(client, args) {
            client.setText($(this).text());
            $('.confirm-copy').text('text copied at ' + $.now()).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Fiddle is not working after updating links to SWF, and JS to my files on server, http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/bEQ6R/16/

Comment: You can also use "beforecopy" event to set the text: it avoids calling setText() for nothing.